# "No results. Previous SQL was not a query" when trying to query DeltaDNA with Python

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I'm currently trying to query a deltadna database. Their Direct SQL Access guide states that any PostgreSQL ODBC compliant tools should be able to connect without issue. Using the guide, I set up an ODBC data source in windows

I have tried adding Set nocount on, changed various formats for the connection string, changed the table name to be (account).(system).(tablename), all to no avail. The simple query works in Excel and I have cross referenced with how Excel formats everything as well, so it is all the more strange that I get the no query problem.

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = 'DSN=name'
query1 = 'select eventName from table_name limit 5'

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR,encoding='utf-8')
query1_cursor = conn.cursor().execute(query1)
row = query1_cursor.fetchone()
print(row)
```

Result is ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

Comment: Try separating out the `cursor()` assignment and `execute()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = 'DSN=name'
query1 = 'select eventName from table_name limit 5'

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR,encoding='utf-8')
query1_cursor = conn.cursor()
query1_cursor.execute(query1)
row = query1_cursor.fetchone()
print(row)
```

You can't do the `cursor` declaration and execution in the same row. Since then your `query1_cursor` variable will point to a cursor object which hasn't executed any query.